# How to start Unity desktop on a headless machine?

Tags: 14.04, unity, vnc, headless

I am trying to get the Untiy desktop (That I am used to using) running on a Ubuntu box that is now headless.

I already have a fake desktop running via the Xorg dummy display driver.
When I VNC into to it however it loads a desktop that just has a terminal.

Can anyone tell me how to get Unity to load despite having no monitor?

Comment: vnc server should autostart if you configured it. raspberry pi uses it exactly the same way. so this should be a configuration problem.

Comment: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1903220

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Unity will not load when running a VNC Virtual Mode session due to the requirement of 3D Graphics, you can run an alternative desktop window manager to get a graphical session however.

To do this you will need to change the `~/.vnc/xstartup` file  (or `/etc/vnc/xstartup` if you do not have one)

There are instructions on the [RealVNC website](https://support.realvnc.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/345/) for this.

Comment: I have a 3D graphics card though. Surely there is a way without using a monitor faking dongle..

Comment: Unfortunately the X server started by a Xvnc (virtual mode) is incapable of using some of the hardware acceleration and 3d acceleration of the graphics card. Using a different window manager will allow you to use a graphical interface for only Xvnc sessions, without affecting the console session.If you run a VNC Server that shows the console session, then this can take advantage of your graphics hardware features, as it will be using the native X session.